# How to get Asciidoctor to render source tags with color

Tags: asciidoctor

I have installed (ver 2.2.6)

```
npm i asciidoctor
```

and run

```
asciidoctor -b xhtml5 -a source-highlighter=rouge .\README.adoc
```

I do get the web page , but the source code is generated flat ..

this is how the the adoc file would display on my intellij IDE with the pluggin

[image]

and this is how my web page would display it

[image]

does anybody know how to generate the web page to have source code css to generate correctly ?

- Addition

I ran the following code after installing rouge

```
        == Introduction :

        :source-highlighter: rouge
        :rouge-style: monokai
        [source,ruby]
        ----
        puts "Hello, Rouge!"
        ----


        :source-highlighter: rouge
        [%linenums,ruby]
        ----
        ORDERED_LIST_KEYWORDS = {
          'loweralpha' => 'a',
          'lowerroman' => 'i',
          'upperalpha' => 'A',
          'upperroman' => 'I'
          # Add more keywords here
        }
        ----

        [source,xml]
        ....
                - id: b-security
                  uri: lb://b-security
                  predicates:
                    - Path=/auth/**

                - id: c-service-A
                  uri: lb://c-service-A
                  predicates:
                    - Path=/service-a/**
                  filters:
                    - AuthenticationFilter
        ....
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the AsciiDoc markup you're using? The markup you are using could make all the difference.

Comment: @eskwayrd i m using [source,java] , [source,xml] & [source,properties]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Rouge syntax highlighter installed?

You can check with:

```
gem list -i rouge
```

If not, [install it](https://github.com/rouge-ruby/rouge).

Note: You won't get the same highlighted view that IntelliJ provides without customization. When I tried Rouge locally, the highlighting worked but it used different colors than your screenshot.

Update:

Apologies, I missed the fact that you are using asciidoctor.js.

Rouge is a syntax highlighter implemented in Ruby, so Ruby Asciidoctor can use its API to highlight syntax. asciidoctor.js cannot use Ruby APIs.

Instead, you could use [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/).

For example:

```
npx asciidoctor -b xhtml5 -a source-highlighter=highlight.js README.adoc
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer
i have installed ruby and rouge , when running gem list -i rouge the answer is true
but if generating a new html file i see nothing changed ..